# How can I use parseInt for a double?

Tags: java

My program receives some input (a `String`). It is rather possible that the input is in the form of a `double`, like `"1.5"`. But I would like to convert it to an `integer`, so I can end up with just a `1`.

First, I tried this:

```
Integer.parseInt(someString);
```

But it doesn't work - I'm assuming it is because of the dot `.` that it can't parse it.

So I thought that maybe the `Integer` class can create an `integer` from a `double`. So I decided to create a `double` and then make it an `int`, like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(Double.parseDouble(someString));
```

But apparently there is

> no suitable method found for parseInt(double)

So, what do you suggest? Are there one-liners for this? I thought about making a method that removes the dot and all characters after it... but that doesn't sound very cool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is safe to parse any numbers as `double`, then convert it to another type after. Like this:

```
// someString = "1.5";
double val = Double.parseDouble(someString);  // -> val = 1.5;
int intVal = (int) Math.floor(val);           // -> intVal = 1;
```

Note that with Java 7 (not tested with earlier JVM, but I think it should work too), this will also yield the same result as above :

```
int intVal = (int) Double.parseDouble(someString);
```

as converting from a floating value to an int will drop any decimal without rounding.

Comment: ... casting! Totally forgot. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

use casting.

```
double val = Double.parseDouble(someString);  
int intVal = (int) Math.floor(val);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the `Double`, I assume, with `Double.parseDouble`. So just use:

```
int i = (int) Double.parseDouble(someString);
```

Comment: ... except, `Double.parseDouble(str)` returns a `double`, and therefore you cannot call `intValue()` on a primitive.

Comment: Ah, excellent point. Thanks for the edit! You could also use the `new Double(String)` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
int no= new Double(string).intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Parse the string as double
2) cast from double to int

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "123.32";
    int i = (int) Math.floor(Double.parseDouble(str));
    System.out.println(i);

}
```